# Cómo saber las ventanas(No procesos) que hay abiertas desde WindowsForms c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, windows, procesos-en-segundo-plano

necesito un poco de orientación, os pongo en contexto:
Estoy intentado hacer un OBS (Programa para grabar y transmitir en Twitch) para mi trabajo de fin de grado y me he quedado un poco atascado a la hora de elegir qué ventanas están abiertas, he probado con algo tal que así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con eso detecto todos los procesos que tiene el sistema, pero cómo puedo diferenciar los que son procesos en segundo plano de los que son por ejemplo aplicaciones como google chrome o juegos como Valorant para poder coger su nombre y mostrarlos al usuario en un comboBox y que luego él lo pueda seleccionar y ya después me las apañaré yo para conseguir la altura y anchura de la aplicación y poder mostrarla.
Por ahora he listado los dispositivos de vídeo (cámaras) que tiene el equipo y puedo grabar la pantalla por completo, el siguiente paso ya sería este, poder elegir qué aplicación quiero grabar y que el programa grabe esa aplicación únicamente. Si alguien necesita más información acerca del proyecto que me diga y le responderé rápidamente. Un saludo.

//INTENTANDO  CONTEXTUALIZAR MEJOR LA PREGUNTA

El tema es que estoy haciendo un OBS y tengo dos desplegables, uno en el que ya cargo todas las cámaras y dispositivos de captura de vídeo del sistema (así que eliges uno y comienzas a grabar) y ahora me gustaría poder tener un desplegable estilo el que tiene OBS donde aparezcan las ventanas que tienes abiertas y al seleccionar una estar seguro que es una ventana que pueda ser grabada y no un proceso cualquiera de windows o algún subproceso de otro programa.

Ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! Bienvenido a SOes, por norma general no se admiten fotografías de código. Puedes editar tu pregunta añadiendo el código? Piensa que si en el futuro el link a tu imagen cae tu pregunta carecería de sentido para futuros miembros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se si he entendido bien tu pregunta , entiendo que quieres una lista de los programas que el usuario tiene abierto tanto navegador, juegos o herramientas.

```
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
            foreach (Process p in processes)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.MainWindowTitle))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(p.MainWindowTitle);
                }
            }
```

Con este código recuperas el título de la ventana principal del proceso. Un proceso tiene asociada una ventana principal solo si el proceso tiene una interfaz gráfica. Si el proceso asociado no tiene una ventana principal (por lo que MainWindowHandle es cero)

Comment: He añadido un poco más de contexto a la pregunta, aunque si el MainWindowTitle sólo se genera con los procesos que tienen interfaz gráfica probablemente eso me sirva y pueda seguir, lo intentaré y mañana comentaré si me funcionó o no, muchas gracias.